# Remote desktop connection using process.startinfo

Tags: vb.net-2010, remote-desktop

I have created an asp.net webpage and from the webpage I am using the code below to establish a remote desktop connection.

rdp.exe is a external file

Here is my code

```
Protected Sub BtnRemote_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles BtnRemote.Click
    Dim Process As New System.Diagnostics.Process     
    Dim startinfo As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    startinfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
    startinfo.FileName = "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe"
    Dim path = "D:\rdp.exe"
    startinfo.Arguments = path + "/v:" + txtTerminal.Text + " " + "/u:" + txtTerUser.Text + " " + "/p:" + txtTerPassword.Text
    startinfo.UseShellExecute = False
    Process.Start(startinfo)
End Sub
```

Everything is fine when I debug, but the system will not establish a remote connection.

But if I use the following command from command prompt, I am able to establish a remote connection.

```
E:\rdp /v:"IPAddress" /domain:"domain" /u:"username" /p:"password"
```

Answer (score 0):

A problem i can see with this is within this line (Also Notice its got the **Path**, **User**, **Password**, and **IP**, **BUT** **is** **missing** the **Domain** Argument):

```
startinfo.Arguments = path + "/v:" + txtTerminal.Text + " " + "/u:" + txtTerUser.Text + " " + "/p:" + txtTerPassword.Text
```

as stated in your CMD arguments it needs to fit this format:

```
E:\rdp /v:"IPAddress" /domain:"domain" /u:"username" /p:"password"
```

However if you notice your **startinfo.arguments** **doesn't contain a space in between the Directory and the IP Address Line** so instead of reading it like this:

```
E:\rdp /v:"IPAddress" /u:"username" /p:"password"
```

it's reading it like this:

```
E:\rdp/v:"IPAddress" /u:"username" /p:"password"
```

just simply fix the line like this:

```
startinfo.Arguments = path + " /v:" + txtTerminal.Text + " /u:""" + txtTerUser.Text + """ /p:" + txtTerPassword.Text
```

*I Also removed the Concatenations of + " " + because all you really need is a
space before the /'s and it will still work properly. Also **notice** that i have added extra quotes, because if the username supports spaces then when it goes to set the argument if the username contains a space then it will count them as two separate arguments quotes around it prevents it from being split into two different arguments*

also instead of using CMD why not start the exe directly by

```
    Dim p As Process
    p.startinfo.FileName = "D:\rdp.exe"
    p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "D:\"
    startinfo.Arguments = path + " /v:" + txtTerminal.Text + " /u:""" + txtTerUser.Text + """ /p:" + txtTerPassword.Text
    p.Start()
```